# wireless hardware switch disabled in a compaq presario CQ57-339WM notebook pc

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I have downloaded and installed the realtek driver for linux based 
on

- what the manufacturer says
- and what the `lspci` cmd shows as given below

  02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)

This is what it says when I use `rfkill list all` cmd in terminal to see what is blocked; check the status results:

```
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

And even earlier today to see if a usb wifi adapter would work, I borrowed one and installed the drivers for it and my tab that list connections listed both as disable by hardware switch and the usb wifi adapter has no switch, so I came to believe my hardware switch on my laptop is blocking any from of wifi. But enternet works just fine. This laptop used to be a windows 7 before I had to get a new hard drive and I installed Ubuntu 12.04.LTS I have never had any trouble with linux or ubuntu until I put it on my laptop

Answer (score 4):

It was the BOIS I went in to the BOIS by hitting F10 before the computer loaded Ubuntu and used the load default setting on the exit tab of the BOIS and then exited the BOIS started Ubuntu up and my wireless is now working and and the hard block is gone

```
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```