# HP nc6400 wireless card not detected

Tags: wireless, networking

Brand new ubuntu user.  Downloaded 12.04 onto my HP nc6400. Everything looks great, except I can't get my wireless to work.  Ethernet is working fine.  I've searched everywhere, but none of the answers I've found make sense.

At the terminal I typed the command  `sudo lshw -C network`

This is the result:

> *-network
>          description: Ethernet interface
>          product: NetXtreme BCM5753M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
>          vendor: Broadcom Corporation
>          physical id: 0
>          bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
>          logical name: eth0

```
   version: 21
   serial: 00:16:d4:c6:14:1c
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.132 duplex=full firmware=5753m-v3.56 ip=192.168.1.114 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:47 memory:e0100000-e010ffff   *-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 02
   serial: 00:19:d2:ab:66:1c
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=3.11.0-17-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg 
   resources: irq:45 memory:e0000000-e0000fff``
```

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
<http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385>

Comment: There is a lot of that file missing, please try again. Thanks

Comment: There is still a lot of information missing from the top of the page.

Comment: I *was* screwing it up!!!   http://pastebin.com/J94ukY4T

Comment: That helps a lot, please post the complete output of: `lsmod` Thanks

Comment: lsmod results  http://pastebin.com/i4Cx0DCz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

wireless should come one if blocks have been removed.

Comment: wireless still not working,unfortunately. This is what I'm seeing on the terminal                                        lake@Lake:~$ sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi
[sudo] password for lake: 
lake@Lake:~$ sudo rfkill unblock all
lake@Lake:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
lake@Lake:~$

Comment: Also, under the network tab at the top it says "wireless disabled by hardware switch."  The wireless switch on the computer is not lit and doesn't respond when pressed.

Comment: The softblock is removed we will have to make it permanent, do you have a key combination like fn+f5 that turns on wifi? hardblock means it is off by the switch usually.

Comment: There is a dedicated button for toggling wifi on and off. It does not respond when pressed.

Comment: Please run `sudo rfkill unblock all` and `sudo rfkill block all` does it change block yes to blocked no? if so there is something we may be able to do to make it work.

Comment: Here are the results: `lake@Lake:~$ sudo rfkill unblock all
[sudo] password for lake: 
lake@Lake:~$  rfkill list all 
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
lake@Lake:~$ sudo rfkill block all
lake@Lake:~$ rfkill list all 
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: yes
lake@Lake:~$`

Comment: I got the wireless working by going into BIOS and resetting to default as per this thread [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427421/wireless-hardware-switch-disabled-in-a-compaq-presario-cq57-339wm-notebook-pc) and then running sudo rfkill unblock all.  Thanks to Wild Man for helping me get on track to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

If your  Wireless not detected to  make  it work you will have to  run wireless from adapter. That's what I used  for my hp laptop and it works good. First you find a wireless adapter that work with linux. Make your running both systems alongside each other also make sure you can see the  other operating system from linux. Then  you install the ireless adapter drivers in  your windows or mac systems you will get some error message about router saying you should put pin # in router don't pay  those messages any mind just  restart you  computer and boot up in linux and wireless adapter lights should come on signal that its working properly.