# Rtl8188ce step by step guide

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek, realtek-wireless

My problem is that my realtek rtl8188ce not work, I have declared Internet through rj32 cable .
I announce accustomed to windows and are completely new to ubuntu .
I have not installed driver and I do not know how to do it
or where I download drivers.
Does anyone have a step by step guide and who could imagine and help a first-time user?
ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)

Comment: Are you quite sure it isn't covered in the driver built in to Ubuntu 14.04? Check: `modinfo rtl8192ce | grep 8176`.

Comment: This is what turn s up.                           alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008176sv*sd*bc*sc*i*

Answer (score 3):

The driver *rtl8192ce* in Ubuntu 14.04 covers your device. If it is not working as expected, something else is wrong. Is the wireless switch or key combination set to enable wireless? Check:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
           Soft blocked: yes
           Hard blocked: yes
```

The wireless switch or key combination is set to disable wireless. Please find it and switch on the wireless.

Your wireless switch, F12, doesn't seem to respond to unblock the wireless. I suggest you try resetting the BIOS to 'Default.' Please see:[wireless hardware switch disabled in a compaq presario CQ57-339WM notebook pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427421/wireless-hardware-switch-disabled-in-a-compaq-presario-cq57-339wm-notebook-pc)

Once we have more information, I will edit my answer to propose a solution.

Comment: 0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: [    9.972596] rtl8192ce: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
[   10.708082] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   10.708407] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[  350.254372] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 1346.477965] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on

Comment: sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Kernel driver just does not work well or at all with this adapter,

Answer (score 0):

The proper driver installs this way. Run in terminal commands (one by one).
But you need to be connected by wire.

```
sudo apt-get install -y git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: This is a bit embarrassing questions?
When the package is ready for installation .
So I've been asked [ J / n] I write when Yes and press enter , but cancel the installation ?
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: You agree. press "J"

Comment: It still cancel the installation.  I press J and enter is this the right way?

Comment: You can always press "y". It is not capital. Small "y" and Enter.

Comment: If there is still a problem, I amended command. It won't ask any more.

Comment: Does the new driver turn on the switch?

Comment: No, it does not, but without the driver it does not work in many cases at all. But is there a switch?

Comment: If it does not work, we need `rfkill list` anyway.

Comment: He has a driver now and he also has`0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: yes Hard blocked: yes`

Comment: Where did you find it? Then there must be a hardware switch, or Fn+something, or in bios.

Comment: Did you try the amended command? It won't ask.

Comment: @Andre Is there a hardware wireless switch somewhere, or some wireless icon on some of F buttons on keyboard? Did you try to press Fn+F2 or something else?

Comment: there is a key on the keyboard but it wont work. i can try fn+f2

Comment: And refresh your browser and try a new command. Maybe that block goes off. And what is laptop model?

Comment: compaq presario cq57 is the make of the pc.

Comment: Try to press F12 button

Comment: I closed terminal, and tryed those commands again,and it installed. but pressing the f12 button dont do nothing.

Comment: [Here is a thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1886539) about this laptop. No solution found.

Comment: when i press f12 the pc goes into fly mode.

Comment: Fly mode is wireless off.

Comment: i tryed to plug the kabel out and try f12 to turn off fly mode and check for internet but no internet

Comment: Did you reboot after you installed the driver and did you click Network Manager icon? Internet won't appear itself. You need to connect to AP first.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24526/discussion-on-answer-by-pilot6-rtl8188ce-step-by-step-guide).